# GEE: Supervised Classification exceed memory

Tags: google-earth-engine, image-classification

I am trying to do a supervised classification using Landsat images, DEM, Slopes, NDVI, etc. Is there any way to do not exceed memory limit?

https://code.earthengine.google.com/4e51f886186d8f373372a499026b2557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to train using more than 1 million points.  That's too many; use less points (maybe a random sample on the sampleRegions results):

```
var less = training.randomColumn().filter(ee.Filter.lt('random', 0.01))
```

Also, you almost certainly need to normalize the elevation values to a range close to 0 to 1.  SVM is touchy about normalized data.